# Custom multiselect lookup width getting increased with each selection

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have created a custom lookup component in lwc from [here](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc). This lookup is working fine.
When I place this component in another component, with each lookup value selection the width of input is getting increased.

What can I do to fix this, so that its width does not get auto increased?

Without selection:
[image]

With Selection:
[image]

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObj__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" disabled="true" ></lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
                <c-lookup
                selection={assignedToInitialSelection}
                errors={errors}
                onsearch={handleSearch}
                onselectionchange={handleSelectionChange}
                label="Contact"
                placeholder="Search Salesforce"
                data-id="selectedContact"
                is-multi-entry={isMultiEntryAssignedTo}></c-lookup>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you could assign flexibility to a var and change it from `auto` to `fixed` (or whatever) after initial load.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you have set the flexibility of your layout-item's to auto.

depending on the behavior you want, you can check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item) for setting a fixed width or adjusting it based on the device being used.

Comment: even if I give other options like no-shrink, it's width is getting changed

Comment: try setting fixed sizes as mentioned in the documentation